# PhpUnit mock database object

Tags: php, phpunit

I want to test different customers buying from a web shop.
The customers are coming from different countries and different VATs apply to them.
Usually the da is coming from a database.
Now I want to mock it.
I have already done it with product in a cart. I have done it like this:

```
protected function setUp(): void {
$this->stub = $this->createMock(Cart::class);
$product = (object) [
        'did' => '212814',
        'amount' => 1,
        'id' => '1664442400',
        'price' => '49.22',
        'name' => 'Table 150 cm',
];
$this->stub->method('getCartProducts')->willReturn([$product]);
```

I wonder if this the right way of doing it.

For the cart it is fine to have just one product in it and use it in different tests.
But I have different customers with different values. How should I create them?
Should I do it like:

```
$this->stubCustomer1 = $this->createMock(Customer::class);
$customer1 = (object) ['name' => 'Paul', 'country' => 'UK']
```

and

```
$this->stubCustomer2 = $this->createMock(Customer::class);
$customer2 = (object) ['name' => 'Paulo', 'country' => 'Italy']
```

and so on.
Like this all are created every time the setup is executed. But not all are needed.
Would it be better to create the customer in every test method?
or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

The common pattern for unit tests is Arrange-Act-Assert (AAA). It means that each test (i.e. each method in your test class) should prepare all the needed state for it itself. This makes tests much more isolated from each other and easier to reason about.

I'd suggest to adhere to this pattern. This will imply that you make all the case-specific preparations directly inside the test methods, not in the `setUp()` method. And `setUp()` can be used only for some generic preparations, mostly technical, not domain-aware, e.g. for resetting some dependencies, clear storages, etc.

In order to simplify the `Arrange` step of your tests, you can create factory methods for different types of customers. And it is not necessary to save each of the stubs in the class property, like `$this->stubCustomer2`, just create them and use in the case, then create new in new case.

So, your test could look like:

```php
// ...

public function test_appropriate_vat_is_applied(): void
{
  // arrange
  $britain_customer = $this->makeCustomer('GB');
  $product_1 = $this->makeProduct('Eggs');
  $product_2 = $this->makeProduct('Milk');
  $cart = $this->makeCart($product_1, $product_2);

  // act
  // ... do something using prepared objects

  // assert
  // ... perform assertions
}

private function makeCustomer(string $country_code): object
{
  // create and return customer with given country code
}

private function makeProduct(string $name): object
{
  // create and return product with given name
}

private function makeCart(object ...$products): object
{
  // create and return cart containinig given products
}
```

Also consider avoiding test doubles as much as possible in favor of real implementations. I.e. maybe it will be better to create real customer, products and carts, instead of stubs. This will make supporting tests easier in the future. In unit tests doubles are really needed only to replace the classes dependent on the out-of-process stuff, like DB, network or filesystem.